# get result of an anonymous PL/SQL

Tags: c#, plsql

I'm trying to execute anonymous PL/SQL in C#. This is my code:

```
var requete = " DECLARE \n";
requete = requete + "type cursor_out is ref cursor; \n";
requete = requete + " cur cursor_out; \n";
requete = requete + "person_row XXX%rowtype; \n";
requete = requete + "procedure Select_Proc(result out cursor_out) is \n";
requete = requete + " begin \n";
requete = requete + "open result for select * from XXX \n";
requete = requete + "end; \n";
requete = requete + "begin \n";
requete = requete + "Select_Proc(cur); \n";
requete = requete + "loop \n";
requete = requete + "fetch cur into person_row; \n";
requete = requete + "exit when cur%notfound; \n";

requete = requete + "end loop; \n";
requete = requete + "close cur; \n";
requete = requete + "end;";

var oc = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
oc.Open();
var cmd = new OracleCommand
{
    Connection = oc,
    CommandText = requete,
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

};
OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

When I run the some PLSQL script in SqlPlus it runs (I added "/"), but in C# I got some error like this one:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: For starters, make it easier on yourself by using multi-line literal syntax in C#: `var requete = @"DECLARE ... [multiple lines here without quote marks or newlines]"` You do NOT put quotes on each line, and you don't insert explicit `\n` newlines. You just break the lines until the very end of the string.

Comment: Okay thank you for this information, it will make my life easier writting the plsql script.

Comment: It is often easier to manage long SQL commands as string resource instead of embedding them in the code.

Comment: @Olivier That is also a valid stratagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `;` after the final `end` in your PL/SQL code.

The `;` (and the `/`) are used by SQL*PLUS to seperate commands. When using ODBC you send in one command at a time, so the `;` isn't needed, and even causes an exception.

Comment: it worked when i was sending simple query, but with PL/SQL code it caused me an exception.